# ListView don't update with updated adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, adapter

I have an activity with refresh button in bar.
Inside this activity have a fragment that calls to asyncTask to get data in json format.
The first time the activity is created, works properly and the listview show everything ok.

When I push my refresh button in the activity bar, I call in the activity to a fragment method 'myOnResume' that calls again to the same async task.

I checked that the json returned by task is updated, but the listview don't update (Using the same method that the first time 'showListaGrupos').

I tried to add the sentence "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();" but still the problem. Listview don't update, and show the same that the first time the activity was created.

Can you help me?

The fragment code:

```
public class GruposFragment extends Fragment {

    View rootView;  
    private Vector<GruposClass> vectorGrupos;
    private ListView lvShowGroups;

    public GruposFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grupos, container, false);
        ActionBar ab = this.getActivity().getActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        lvShowGroups = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvGroups);
   String       id="1";
        GruposTask getGrupos = new GruposTask(GruposFragment.this, getActivity());
        getGrupos.execute(id);

        return rootView;
    }

//called from onPostExecute 
public void showListaGrupos(String result) {
        vectorGrupos=new Vector<GruposClass>();

            //create the vector with json returned.   
                    for(...){
                      vectorGrupos.add(new GruposClass(x,y,z...));
                      }   

if(adapter==null){
        adapter = new adapterGroupsClasses(getActivity());
    }else{
        adapter.changeListVals();
    }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        lvShowGroups.setAdapter(adapter);

        lvShowGroups.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                ...
            }
        });
    }

    class adapterGroupsClasses extends ArrayAdapter<GruposClass> {

        Activity context;

        adapterGroupsClasses(Activity context) {
            super(context, R.layout.listitem_groupsline, vectorGrupos);
            this.context = context;
        }

     public void changeListVals(){
      this.clear();
      this.addAll(vectorGrupos);
    }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View item = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(item == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_groupsline, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.id = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.TvIdGroup);
            holder.nombre = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.TvName);
            holder.descripcion = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.TvDescription);    

            item.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)item.getTag();
        }

        holder.id.setText(vectorGrupos.get(position).getId());
        holder.nombre.setText(vectorGrupos.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.descripcion.setText(vectorGrupos.get(position).getDescripcion());            

        return(item);
    }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView id;
        TextView nombre;
        TextView descripcion;
    }

//called from Activity bar button refresh
    public void myOnResume() {
        GruposTask getGrupos = new GruposTask(GruposFragment.this, getActivity());
        getGrupos.execute(id);
    }

}
```

The class of the Vector is:

```
public class GruposClass {
        private String id;
        private String nombre;
        private String descripcion;

        public GruposClass(String i, String n, String d){
            id=i;
            nombre = n;
            descripcion = d;
        }
        public String getNombre(){
            return nombre;
        }
        public String getDescripcion(){
            return descripcion;
        }
        public String getId(){
            return id;
        }
    }
```

And the activity is:

```
public class Grupos extends FragmentActivity {

    GruposFragment mainFragment;
    Bundle instance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        instance=savedInstanceState;
        super.onCreate(instance);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grupos);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new GruposFragment()).commit();
        }

        mainFragment = (GruposFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.listGroup);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        createMenu(menu);
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.grupos, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void createMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem itemRefresh = menu.add(0,1,1,"refresh");
        {
            itemRefresh.setIcon(R.drawable.refresh);
            itemRefresh.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);           
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        ...
        if (id == 1) {
            mainFragment.myOnResume();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

The layout of the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView  android:id="@+id/textViewGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:text="@string/cabeceraGrupos" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/lvGroups" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

(The listView is a custom Listview)

thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refresh list on click of button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379848/refresh-list-on-click-of-button)

Comment: I don't use Base adapter in my code

Comment: can you try to add vectorGrupos=new Vector<GruposClass>(); this is global and inside showListaGrupos clear it and then assign values

Comment: @SreejithSP its not the same at all

Comment: @Android still not working :/

Comment: I hope you added the changeListVals function to your adapter class..I think you would have..but i dont see it in the code

Comment: am stumped..the only other issue i could find was a missing @Override for the getView method.
and check this tutorial..http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#arrayAdapter

sorry cant help more

Comment: Yes, yes, I added `changeListVals `, I forgot to copy and paste when I edited.
On the other side, I also add @Override anotation in getView but still the problem. I'm going to read the article.

I dont know what happens, but anyway I want to thank you for all your help!
regards!

Answer (score 1):

you are re-initializing a new adapter everytime,and you are calling notifydatasetchanged on the new adapter instance,not the older one.
try this structure once

```
public class GruposFragment extends Fragment {

...     
private Vector<GruposClass> vectorGrupos;
private ListView lvShowGroups;
private adapterGroupsClasses adapter;

public GruposFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grupos, container, false);
    ...

    lvShowGroups = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvGroups);

    GruposTask getGrupos = new GruposTask(GruposFragment.this, getActivity());
    getGrupos.execute(id);

    return rootView;
}

//called from onPostExecute

public void showListaGrupos(String result) {
    vectorGrupos=new Vector<GruposClass>();
...

    //create the vector with json returned.      
if(adapter!=null){
    adapterGroupsClasses adapter = 
            new adapterGroupsClasses(getActivity());
            }else{
adapter.changeListVals();
            }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



    lvShowGroups.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            ...
        }
    });
}

class adapterGroupsClasses extends ArrayAdapter<GruposClass> {

    Activity context;

    adapterGroupsClasses(Activity context) {
        super(context, R.layout.listitem_groupsline, vectorGrupos);
        this.context = context;
    }

   public void changeListVals(){
  this.clear();
  this.addAll(vectorGrupos);

}

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View item = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(item == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_groupsline, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            ... 
        return(item);
    }
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView id;
    TextView nombre;
    TextView descripcion;
}

//called from Activity bar button refresh
public void myOnResume() {
    GruposTask getGrupos = new GruposTask(GruposFragment.this, getActivity());
    getGrupos.execute(id);
}

}
```

Comment: With your code, im having ForcedClose.
Now, I changed `if(adapter!=null)` to `if(adapter==null)` and don't have FC, but still not updating :/

Comment: can you paste your entire code?with all the class dependencies etc.Then I can give you a specific answer

Comment: Edited now, If you need something more code just say me. Thanks!